# How to call functions inside ternary operators in UnityScript?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ternary-operator, unityscript, side-effects

I'm trying to decide which function to call, based on a boolean value.

```
myBooleanVariable ? function1() : function2();
```

Unity gives the error :

> Expressions in statements must only be executed for their
>   side-effects.

So why does this not work, and how can I make it work ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Something tells me you've left an important word out of that error message *("...must **not** be...")*.

Comment: It works for me, can you provide more details.

Comment: Does your functions return anything?

Comment: @Asterisk: Are you using UnityScript? (Unity's implementation of JavaScript)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I copy pasted the error message. [@]ABP no, they are void functions. And I'm using a JavaScript file inside Unity, I don't know if it's called UnityScript.

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: Then there's almost certainly a typo in Unity. :-) It makes no sense as it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with you. But still not sure what is meant by side-effects, and I have no idea what is an expression and what is a statement, so I cannot comment any further :)

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: A [side-effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) is a result of a function that isn't its return value. You're using the conditional operator to call one of two functions, and its complaining (I *think*) because although you're using an operator (in an expression), you're not doing anything with the return value, and so only using it to get the side effects. An *expression* is something that can be used as a right-hand value (the right-hand side of an assignment, passed into a function, etc.); *statement* is harder to define concisely. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why does this not work, and how can I make it work ?

If it's true that it doesn't work (I don't have Unity to hand), it means UnityScript (Unity's implementation of JavaScript) doesn't support the [expression statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4). Which puts it at variance with the specification, and means a fair number of JavaScript idioms won't work in it. Your line is perfectly valid JavaScript/ECMAScript. You might check to see if there are "lint"-style options you can enable/disable.

The solution would be to use the result of the expression, or rewrite that using `if`.

Use the result:

```
var f = myBooleanVariable ? function1() : function2();
```

Using `if`:

```
if (myBooleanVariable) {
    function1();
}
else {
    function2();
}
```

Or if you really want the `if` to be on one line:

```
if (myBooleanVariable) function1(); else function2();
```

Comment: Yep, I did as your last line. I just wanted to know if I'm skipping something about ternary operators. Thanks !

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: You're not in true *JavaScript*, no; your "ternary" line (more properly, your "[conditional expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12)" line) works just fine in true JavaScript.

Comment: ok then, I will blame Unity :) Thanks again ! accepting in 1 min.

Comment: It might also be a (sane) style control, which would then probably be configurable somewhere (never tried Unity, so pure speculation).

Comment: @JanDvorak Some IDE and stuff let you define what problems should render as warnings or errors. Personally I don't like warnings, they accumulate. Code should just be right or wrong.

Comment: @dystroy tell this to Android developers :)